# Using existing custom UIView in interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, xib

I made an UIView subclass because I needed something custom.

Then, I added an UIView on one of my xibs and changed the class of from UIView to my custom class. When I run, it doesn't instantiate the custom class.

What do I have to do? What constructor will be used to instantiate the custom class?

Comment: There's no custom constructor, How are you checking that is not initiated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xib` will be instantiated with

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
```

If you are relying on connections and other objects in the `xib` to be available then you may also add code to

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
```

which is when the object `... is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.`

---

To deal with code duplication you can do something like the following

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    [self commonInit];
  }
  return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if (self) {
    [self commonInit];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)commonInit
{
  // any common setup
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method called when you create an UIView from a XIB is

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
```